# Force individual y axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), y = c(24L, 27L, 18L, 
23L, 28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))

  x  y
1 2 24
2 3 27
3 4 18
4 5 23
5 1 28
```

I want to set the y axis limits to `0` and `39` but I get `0` and `40`.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  ylim(0,39)
```

[image]

Comment: @mnist This is very helpful and I think the solution. Thank you very much. Though I would like to know if there is a possibility to set this limits without setting breaks that are divisible by 39. So to say with individual gaps between 0 and 39. So for example like 0-10-20-30-39.

Comment: seq just creates a vector. you can define whatever you want using `c(...)`

Comment: `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 39), breaks = seq(c(0, 10, 20, 39)))` does not work.

Comment: Ah ok now I see it. @mnist please provide as answer!. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set breaks as you wish using the breaks argument. Breaks do not need to be a regular sequence.

```r
  df <- structure(list(x = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), y = c(24L, 27L, 18L, 
                                                        23L, 28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
                                                                                                        "4", "5"))
  
  
  library(ggplot2)
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
    geom_point()+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 39),
                       breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 39))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `limits` and `breaks` in the `scale_y_continuous` function to whatever you want. To visualize you can use this code:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), y = c(24L, 27L, 18L, 
                                                      23L, 28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
                                                                                                      "4", "5"))

    library(ggplot2)
    
    ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
      geom_point()+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 39), breaks = seq(0, 39, by = 13))
```

Output:

[image]